# Deleting non mandatory FIX messages/fields from data dictionary

Tags: fix-protocol

Is it good practise to delete FIX fields/messages from a data dictionary which we don't use? I have a developer who says the data dictionary should only contain those fields/messages which venues use. However, having looked at myriad data dictionaries from various venues,I noticed they contain FIX messages/fields even though they do not use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding DDs, my general opinion is "if it ain't broke don't fix it".  Most people just take the default DD and make only enough changes to fit the target venue.  You could go in and remove everything else, but I don't think that'd be a good use of a few man-hours (though not explicitly harmful if you don't make any mistakes).

The DD file format is simple enough, and DDs change so seldom anyway, that leaving them in doesn't create a maintainability problem.

Sounds like your developer is... let's say a "detail-oriented personality".  Give him some new work to do and he'll forget about this.